# Inserting initial data after database creation in SQLite.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I have a SQLite database that I want to populate with some initial data.

Using [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#building-complex-queries), this method seems to be working:

```
do {
    let _ = try db.run( userDictionary.create(ifNotExists: false) {t in
        t.column(wordId, primaryKey: true)
        t.column(word, unique: true)
        t.column(frequency, defaultValue: 1)
        t.column(following, defaultValue: "")
        })

} catch _ {
    print("table already exists")
    return
}

// Add some initial data for a new database
print("adding new data")
myMethodToInsertInitialData()
```

The way this works, though is that I am using `ifNotExists: false` to throw an error every time after the initial database creation. (Setting it to `true` would not throw an error (or allow the early return).) However, throwing an error on purpose every time except the first time seems like poor programming. I don't really mean it as an error. I just want to insert some data in a newly created database. Is there a better way to do this or is this what everyone does?

Comment: You could set a Boolean in `NSUserDefaults` or a Property list `plist` to check if it is the first time running the app.

Comment: @TPlet, I considered that and it is a valid option. The reason I am leaning away from it, though, is that I could conceivably delete the database table and recreate it some time after the first run. With the above method, I add the initial data when (and only when) the database table gets created.

Comment: Oh well ok. I didn't use SQLite.swift so I have a question here: In the docs it says that you can access a Table with e.g. `let users = Table('users')` . What happens if this table does not exist? Is it just nil, or does it crash? `

Comment: This creates a SQLite.swift table, not the actual database table, so there is no crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether data is available in table or not in [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)

```
do
{
    db = try Connection(YOUR_DB_PATH)
    let intCount : Int64  = db.scalar("SELECT count(*) FROM yourTableName") as! Int64
    if (intCount == 0)
    {
        //callWebServiceCall()
    }
    else
    {
        //getDataFromDB()
    }
}
catch
{
    print("error")
}
```

Comment: When I read the documentation I didn't understand scalars very well. So even if the table grows to be very large, this will be a fast lookup, correct?

Comment: @Suragch Yes It will just count!